# apache redirector to redirect custom url to aws internal dns name

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-2.4, proxy, reverse-proxy, mod-rewrite

I am using reverse proxy redirecting to internal DNS name of load balancer. As the internal DNS name of Load balancer is too long, I am getting an error

```
 ProxyPass worker hostname (internal-xxxxxx-xxxxxx.xxxxxx-xxxxx.xxxx.com) too long
```

I am trying to use redirector rule, 
Redirect "xxxx" "internal-xxxxxx-xxxxxx.xxxxxx-xxxxx.xxxx.com"

In my ProxyPass, I used

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        ProxyPass / https://xxxx:443/
 61      ProxyPassReverse / https://xxxx:443/
 62    </IfModule>
```

This redirection is not working. I dont want to create a DNS entry and was trying to use the redirector to make it work. Any ideas on what could be wrong. Appreciate any help.

Comment: "I dont want to create a DNS entry" - for what? How does it resolve without a DNS entry? Where exactly is your "Redirect"? How long is "too long"?

Comment: I was wondering if there is a way to use redirector. The internal DNS entry for LB is around 68 chars. With Apache >=2.4, there is a limit of 96 characters for ProxyPass hostname. Not sure why apache was triggerring that error. I was thinking of using a redirector to avoid the large internal DNS name. We can use DNS entries to resolve it, but everytime we drop and recreate a LB, you get a different internal DNS name